# Convert current datetime to long in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I want to convert the current datetime to a long value in Java.

I know it has to be something with the DateTime

```
DateTime datetime = new DateTime();
```

But I couldn't find a way to convert the dateTime to long.

Comment: [It's in the Javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html#getMillis%28%29)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you mean **current** or **now** then `System.currentTimeMillis()` will do it for you. More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Answer (score 31):

The other answers are correct.

## Four ways to count-from-epoch

To spell it out in detail, here are four ways to get the number of milliseconds since the [Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) [Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29), the beginning of January 1, 1970 in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/[GMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmt) (no time zone offset). Presented in order of preference.

### java.time

The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later is defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). These classes supplant the outmoded java.util.Date/Calendar classes. These classes are inspired by Joda-Time but are re-architected.

The java.time classes are capable of holding nanosecond resolution. In Java 8 specifically, capturing the current moment is limited to milliseconds, due to an old implementation of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html). Java 9 brought a fresh implementation of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) capable of capturing the current moment in finer resolution, limited by the capability of the host OS and host hardware. On Oracle JDK 9.0.4 on macOS Sierra, I get values in [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond), for six digits of decimal fraction.

The `Instant` class includes a convenience method [`toEpochMilli`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--) provides milliseconds. Beware of data loss, as any [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) or [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) in the `Instant` are ignored when generating a count of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).

```
long millis = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
```

### `System`

The `System` class’ method [currentTimeMillis](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) works. But chances are that you are doing some other work with date-time values. If so, skip System and just use the date-time classes.

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

### Joda-Time

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is the popular third-party open-source library used in place of `java.util.Date`/`Calendar`. Its main class is [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), so perhaps this is what you had in mind given your question's use of that term.

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). The team advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

```
long millis = org.joda.time.DateTime.now().getMillis();
```

### `java.util.Date`

This class is best avoided, along with its siblings `java.util.Calendar` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The troublesome old date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted by java.time classes. But for your specific purpose, this class *does* work.

```
long millis = new java.util.Date().getTime();
```

By the way, I do *not* recommend tracking time as a count-from-[epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). Makes debugging difficult, and near impossible to spot invalid data as humans cannot interpret a `long` as a date-time. Also, ambiguous as different systems use [different epoch reference dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing), and use different granularities of whole seconds, [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond), [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond), [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), and others.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're using [joda-time](http://joda-time.sf.net), the following line will sort you:

```
datetime.getMillis()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29), which returns a `long`. Or, you can call [BaseTime.getMillis()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html#getMillis%28%29). Either will give you the date and time as a `long`.